# adding characters in an array at specific points

Tags: java

I'm working on a Caesar cipher and I've gotten the majority of the code to work as planned.
the code is supposed to

1. remove all special characters and spaces
2. bring everything to uppercase
3. add spaces at an inputted interval any additional leftover spaces with x's

so for example if i were to type

`plaintext: Hi im Doug
key: 1
buffer: 3`

my output should be

`IJJ NEP VHX`

now I've gotten everything to work but the buffer part

this is my code in its entirety

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter plaintext: ");
        Scanner pTextInp = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pText = pTextInp.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter key value: ");
        Scanner kInp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int key = kInp.nextInt();
        pText = normalizeText(pText);
        pText = caesarify(pText, key);
        System.out.print("Enter desired grouping number: ");
        Scanner grpInp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int grpInt = grpInp.nextInt();
        pText = groupify(grpInt, pText);
        System.out.println(pText);
    }
    // CONVERT STRING TO A CHAR ARRAY
    public static char[] sArray(String s) {
        int sLen = s.length();
        char[] sChar = new char[sLen + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < sLen; i++){
            sChar[i] = s.charAt(i);
        }
        return sChar;
    }

    public static String caesarify(String s, int k) {
        int sLen = s.length();
        char cText[] = sArray(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < sLen; i++){
            int j =  cText[i] - 65;
            int l = (((j + k) % 26) + 65);
            cText[i] = (char) l;
        }
        s = new String(cText);
        return s;
    }

    // normalizes text (removes all spaces and special characters)
    public static String normalizeText(String s) {
            int sLen = s.length();
            char[] t1 =  s.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < sLen; i++ ){
                if(t1[i] < 'A' || t1[i] > 'z' || (t1[i] > 'Z' && t1[i] < 'a')) {
                    t1[i] = ' ';
                }
                else{
                    t1[i] = s.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            String t = new String(t1);
            t  = t.replaceAll(" ", "" );
            t = t.toUpperCase();
            return t;
    }

     public static String groupify(int i , String s){
        int sLen = s.length();
        char[] t = new char[sLen];
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++){
            t[j] = s.charAt(j);
            if ( j % i == 0) {
            t[j] = ' ';
            sLen++;
        }
        }
        s = new String(t);
        return s;
    }
```

and this is the section in particular that i think is the issue

```
  public static String groupify(int i , String s){
        int sLen = s.length();
        char[] t = new char[sLen];
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++){
            t[j] = s.charAt(j);
            if ( j % i == 0) {
            t[j] = ' ';
            sLen++;
        }
        }
        s = new String(t);
        return s;
    }
```

with this this if i input

```
Hi Im Doug
```

I get

```
 JJ EP H
```

as output

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Please fix your broken keyboard. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia than a chat room.

Comment: "now ive gotten everything to work but the buffer part" is kind of vague, isn't it? When you post a question, you need to provide a clear problem statement. What, exactly, is wrong with the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code `t[i] += ' '` is adding the space character's value to value in the array. That's not what you want. Rather you want to be storing a space in next position. I also suggest that you use better names for your variable - single character variables should generally only be used for indexes.

```
int pos = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++)
    result[pos++] = input.charAt(j);
     if ( j % group == 0) {
        result[pos++] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: it giving me an error that the string is out of bounds when i attempt to implement your code pos++ should increase the size of the array though should it now?

Answer (score 0):

For the code You have highlighted you are missing curly brackets after the for Loop. Try to define j outside the for-loop and assign the value 0 to j in the for-loop. It would be a better practice if you Store the size of your new Char-Array in a separate variable as it is easier to read when finding bugs in the code.